# Formatting a string in Javascript using DOJO

Tags: javascript, replace, dojo

I have a JSON file and I need to replace one Property in it using DOJO Format.
This is my JSON File.

```
{
    "In1": "00",
    "In2": "01",
    "In3": "02",
    "In4": "04",
    "Pay": "$pay",
}
```

my code is :

```
require(["dojo/string"],function(string) {
   object.["Pay"] = string.substitute("${pay}", { replace: "ABC"});
});
```

I need to replace {$pay} with "ABC"

Its coming to string undefined :(.

Comment: waht you want to achieve , just change object value ? because here using substitution is nott the right choise , its used for other stuff ?

Comment: @SpringerF Yes I want to change the object value like '$pay' in the json file to 'ABC'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that  doesn't require extras lib just use the [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace) function to change what ever you want , whether using text or regular expression

see below snippet :

```js
object = {
  "In1": "00",
  "In2": "01",
  "In3": "02",
  "In4": "04",
  "Pay": "$pay",
}

object["Pay"] = object["Pay"].replace("$pay", "ABC")

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out :)

Here is what I used.

`require(["dojo/string"],function(string) {
 object.["Pay"] = string.substitute("${pay}", { pay: "ABC"});});`

But couldn't figure out a way, if the JSON is like

```
{
 "Pay": "$pay",
}
```

:(